# Parsing Poorly Formed HTML/XML-ish Content

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to parse content from a remote server that I have absolutely no control over that returns content similar to this:

```
<alpha>
<bravo>123
<charlie>Some
Multiline
Text
</alpha>

<alpha>
<bravo>456
<charlie>More text
</alpha>
```

`BeautifulSoup` does an interesting job parsing the markup by interpreting it as such:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <alpha>
        <bravo>123
        <charlie>Some
        Multiline
        Text</charlie></bravo>
        </alpha>

        <alpha>
        <bravo>456
        <charlie>More text</charlie></bravo>
        </alpha>
    </body>
</html>
```

Though I would like something similar to this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <alpha>
        <bravo>123</bravo>
        <charlie>Some
        Multiline
        Text</charlie>
        </alpha>

        <alpha>
        <bravo>456</bravo>
        <charlie>More text</charlie>
        </alpha>
    </body>
</html>
```

So that I parse it into some kind of array of `alpha`s with a structure similar to this:

```
[
    { bravo: ... , charlie: ... }
    { bravo: ... , charlie: ... }
]
```

I can't just read the content of each node until the next newline because contents sometimes span multiple lines.

Does anybody have an idea for a way I could parse this? or recommend another library to use?

Comment: whats wrong with how beautiful soup does it?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I can't separate the `bravo` and `charlie` values because it nests them in an attempt to fix the markup

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse it in [`xml` features turned on](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml) to let it use `lxml` XML parser under-the-hood.

```
BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
```

Note, this requires `lxml` module to be installed.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <alpha>
... <bravo>123
... <charlie>Some
... Multiline
... Text
... </alpha>
... 
... <alpha>
... <bravo>456
... <charlie>More text
... </alpha>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
>>> print soup.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha>
 <bravo>
  123
  <charlie>
   Some
Multiline
Text
  </charlie>
  <alpha>
   <bravo>
    456
    <charlie>
     More text
    </charlie>
   </bravo>
  </alpha>
 </bravo>
</alpha>
```

As a side note, run [`diagnose()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose) and see how different parsers parse the input data you have.

---

Here is how you can get the desired list of dictionaries:

```
print [{'bravo': alpha.bravo.get_text(strip=True),
        'charlie': alpha.charlie.get_text(strip=True)}
       for alpha in soup('alpha')]
```

Prints:

```
[
    {'bravo': u'123Some\nMultiline\nText456More text', 'charlie': u'Some\nMultiline\nText'}, 
    {'bravo': u'456More text', 'charlie': u'More text'}
]
```

Comment: first off, thanks so much for your detailed response, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to only read the contents of each tag without including the contents of all the following tags. I didn't make this clear in my OP, in your example the `bravo` values still include the `charlie` values, I need to keep them separate, despite the horrible markup the server responds with

Comment: @Greg you are welcome. Is it something you get every single time from the server? In other words, are `bravo` and `charlie` always coming without closing tags? Thanks.

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes, each object has the exact same properties/child tags

Comment: @Greg first of all, as you can see, you can still get the values in a list of dicts (even if internally in `BeautifulSoup` `alpha`s children are nested..)

Comment: @Greg but, yeah, we can though still rearrange the nodes after loading it with `BeautifulSoup` - move the `charlie` one level up.